# How to make OAuth tokens with different validity lifetime with Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I was able to make OAuth tokens with Spring Security with following in my `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`:

```java
@Override
public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
        .inMemory()
            .withClient(AppConst.CLIENT_ID)
                .secret(AppConst.CLIENT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(AppConst.GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AppConst.GRANT_TYPE_REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .scopes(AppConst.TOKEN_HEADER)
                // Here I provide the validity timeperiod
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(AppConst.ACCESS_TOKEN_VALID_SECONDS);
}
```

So my use case is that I want to provide different token validity period for mobile app users (say 1 week) and the web app users (say 1 hour).

How can this be done apart from a global configuration?

Comment: You could use different clients for mobile and web app. Or at least different client id and secrete.

Comment: @dur From what I understand, `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` is loaded only once, when application start up. How can I modify this behaviour, or get a different client based on request parameters?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Could you elaborate it? It is no problem that the `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter `is only once loaded. The configuration is not changing while runtime.

Comment: @dur When a request comes in, it is then I need to decide the token validity. You pointed out that this is achievable by making multiple clients. How can I use a particular client for a particular request so that their token validity is different? Code examples will be nice.

Comment: Both clients have different tokens, because they have to login separatly with own client id and secret. You don't have to decide (on server-side) which client makes the call. I don`t undestand what kind of example code you need. The code is in your question.